# Transfer Billing State to Shipping State

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, plugins

I am working on an e-commerce site that works with Woocommerce. On the Checkout page, I'm trying to import the data I get from the Billing Details into the Shipping Details. I have defined a checkbox for this. By ticking the checkbox, the data is transferred. So far, no problem.

I can transfer data such as First Name, Last Name. But unfortunately I can't pass State (selected value). The problem arises probably because it is a select box. However, I couldn't find the problem. Below is the jQuery code I wrote for this. I'll be glad if it helps.

```
jQuery("[name='billing_state']").filter(":selected").val(jQuery("[name='shipping_state']").filter(":selected").val());
```

Comment: By default if customer doesnt provide shipping details woocommerce understand this as same as billing details. If you still want to copy the information in to the shipping i would update the order on thankyou action not before that and w/o jquery.

Comment: No problem at that point. I think you misunderstood. After filling the Billing Information, a new checkbox will be opened if the customer says send to a different address. It can then transfer all the data.
The only problem here is getting State in Billing Info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the code below, this works for me with the default theme "Twenty Twenty-One".

Billing state to Shipping state:

```
jQuery("[name='shipping_state']").val(jQuery("[name='billing_state']").val()).change();
```

Shipping state to Billing state:

```
jQuery("[name='billing_state']").val(jQuery("[name='shipping_state']").val()).change();
```